# How to use iframe or something similar for external websites

Tags: php, html, iframe

One of my clients needs me to insert an external website of his into the new website I'm developing, I tried just including it with an iframe, but I quickly learned that the imported website needs to have X-Frame-Options header set to allow my site.

I have access to both websites, so I tried doing so, I tried both with php and in the apache settings, but it never worked. After some searching, I found out that firefox and chrome just don't support X-Frame-Options allow-from.

How can I get around this? Is there another way to get iframes working? Or is there something else I can use besides an iframe? I've been searching for quite some time and all I can find is people mentioning X-Frame-Options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems that my problem wasn't actually what I thought it was, turns out that the website I wanted to iframe was in http, while the one I made had ssl. It just completely slipped my mind, and once I added ssl to the other website, everything worked just fine.